# I am trying to create a login system using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, authentication

This is my first project in Python but the login feature is not working properly.
The problem area is: `{if pattern_account.match(x) == login_info:}`

It is not matching as desired. Here is the full code:

```
import re

print("Login System\n\n\n")
print('Login or Sign up\n')
a = input('Press L for login and S For Sign Up\n')
Email = None
Password = None
confirm_password = None
regex_email = '(^[a-zA-z0-9]+@[a-zA-z0-9]+\.[a-zA-z]+$)'
regex_password = '(^[a-zA-z0-9_]*[A-Z0-9]+[a-zA-z0-9]{8,}$)'


def login():
    Email = input("Enter Your email\n")
    if re.search(regex_email, Email):
        pass
    else:
        print('Please enter valid email')
        raise SystemExit("")
    Password = input('Enter your Password\n')
    if re.search(regex_password, Password):
        pass
    else:
        print('Password should be have at least 8 characters ,at least 1 capital letter and 1 number   ')
        quit()
        raise SystemExit("")

    return Email, Password


def signup():
    Email = input("Enter Your email\n")
    if re.search(regex_email, Email):
        pass
    else:
        print('Please enter valid email')
        raise SystemExit("")
    Password = input('Type your New Password\n')
    confirm_password = input('Confirm your new password\n')
    if Password == confirm_password:
        print('Password matched')
    else:
        print("Please Type same Password")
        raise SystemExit("")
    if re.search(regex_password, Password):
        pass
    else:
        print('Password should be have at least 8 characters ,at least 1 capital letter and 1 number   ')
        quit()
        raise SystemExit("")

    return Email, Password


if a == "L":

    account_check = open('account.txt', "r")
    login_info = str(login())

    for x in account_check:

        pattern_account = re.compile(login_info)

        if pattern_account.match(x) == login_info:
            print("Logged in Successfully\n Thank YOU")
            raise SystemExit("Goodbye")


elif a == 'S':

    account_registration = str(signup())
    account_register = open('account.txt', 'a')
    account_register.write(account_registration + '\n')

    print('Successfully registered')
else:
    print('Please give valid input\n')
    raise SystemExit()
```

I just want a little bit of guidance on how to get the whole thing to loop after a certain input by a user - like after signing up or after providing the wrong email while logging in etc.

Comment: What's with all those `raise SystemExit(...)` calls? What are you trying to do by raising exceptions?

Comment: trying to stop the code by raising exceptions since I don't know how to rerun the code